# Are Array's coerced when used with ES6's String.include function?

Tags: javascript, string, ecmascript-6

I've been learning ES6 recently using multiple tutorials and programming exercises. I have just come across an exercise involving the String.include function. The exercise states that String.includes can **coerce an array** and find its values in the string we call 'includes' on. Unfortunately, I'm failing to understand how this works. A simple example:

```
'123'.includes([1,2,3]) // false
```

The call returns false, but the exercise is saying it should return true. Any ideas?

Comment: [Array's toString method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/toString#Description) joins the array elements by a comma, `,`, so `[1,2,3]` becomes the strnig: `"1,2,3"` which is why you are getting false

Comment: This doesn't answer my question. My question is whether or not the function does, in fact, coerce an array.

Comment: Can you link the tutorial you are following?

Answer (score 0):

I found that the reason why my code was failing was that I was failing to include commas in the string I was calling includes on.

Arrays ARE coerced, but they are coerced precisely:

```
'123'.includes([1,2,3]);     // false
'1,2,3'.includes([1,2,3]);   // true
```